# Ensure order that subscribers get updated

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

Is there a way to make sure the order on how subscribers get updated is ensured?

I've got a hot observable and my first subscriber does some sync work to update a variable and my next subscriber then has to initialise a service (only once!), and only after that variable is ensured to be set!

it looks like this:

```
import App from './App'

var appSource = App.init() // gets the hot observable

// our second subscriber
appSource.take(1).subscribe(() => {
  // take 1 to only run this once
  nextService.init()
})
```

where `App.init` looks like this:

```
...
init() {
  var source = this.createObservable() // returns a hot interval observable that fetches a resource every few minutes

  // first subscriber, updates the `myVar` every few minutes
  source.subscribe((data) => this.myVar = data)

  return source
}
...
```

this currently works, but I am unsure if it will always follow the order 100%.

**EDIT:**

As I've heard, subscribers will be invoked FIFO. So the order is somewhat assured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if RxJS ever explicitly guarantees that observers are called in order of subscription.  But, as you say, it usually works.

However, you might consider modelling your actual workflow instead of relying on implicit observer order.

It sounds like you need to know when your app is initialized so you can take further action.  Instead of relying on knowledge of the internal workings of `App.init`, `App` could expose an API for this:

One (non-Rx way) is to let the caller supply a callback to `init`:

```
//...
init(callback) {
  var source = this.createObservable() // returns a hot interval observable that fetches a resource every few minutes

  // first subscriber, updates the `myVar` every few minutes
  source.subscribe((data) => {
    this.myVar = data;
    if (callback) {
        callback();
        callback = undefined;
    }
  })

  return source
}

// elsewhere
App.init(() => nextService.init());
```

Another option instead of a callback is to just have `init` return a `Promise` that your resolve (or an `Rx.AsyncSubject` that you signal) once initialization is complete.

And yet another option, but requires a bit of a refactor, is to model `this.myVar` as the observable data that it is.  i.e.:

```
init() {
    this.myVar = this.createObservable().replay(1);
    this.myVar.connect();
    // returns an observable that signals when we are initialized
    return this.myVar.first();
}

// elsewhere, you end up with this pattern...
const servicesToInit = [ App, service1, service2, service3 ];
Observable
    .of(servicesToInit)
    .concatMap(s => Rx.Observable.defer(() => s.init()))
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(results => {
        // all initializations complete
        // results is an array containing the value returned by each service's init observable
    });
```

Now, anything that wants to make use of `myVar` would always need to subscribe to it in someway to get the current and/or future values.  They could never just synchronously ask for the current value.

Comment: Hey @Brandon, thanks for your great explanation! Question about the `myVar`: currently, `myVar` represents data that comes from a resource that I have to fetch every few minutes. To get this data I simple added a `App.getData()` which returns `this.myVar` whenever I need it. I'd have to refactor my getMethod to something like `getData => this.myVar.takeLast(1)` to get the latest data, that correct?

Comment: Even worse: you'd have to make `getData` async: `getData => this.myVar.first()` and call it like so: `getData().subscribe(data => value available here);`.  Async has a tendency to spread once you start using it.  That's why I said it is quite a bit of a refactor if you are currently representing it as being synchronously available.

Comment: One alternative is to do this:  `this.myVarAsync = this.createObservable().do(val => this.myVar = val).replay(1);`.  That would make the "most recent" value available as a simple variable, while making the asynchronously changing value available as an observable for anyone that needs it.

Comment: I see, I guess I'll go with the callback as there is no need to go that much crazy here. Thank you very much!